# How can i use a URL to call a python script

Tags: java, android, python

In my java code, I want to be able to call a URL and that URL should run my python script. Does anyone have a recommendation?

I have tried using Heroku to host the python script but I will also like an alternative

When I host my python code on my local server I can call the URL and the python script runs

But I want to be able to host the python script somewhere else so I can call the URL from my android app

Comment: Are you asking advices on python hosting services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some kind of server to receive the request I have an example of flask here.
A server-side code to receive and use the POST request using flask would look like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def result():
    print(request.form['foo']) # should display 'bar'
    return 'Received !' # response to your request.
```

This is the simplest & quickest way to send/receive a POST request using python.

You can also use java to send the POST request.

Comment: Thanks man. But where do i host it?. Its currently hosted on my localhost and when i try to call it from there it works perfectly. But how do i host it somewhere else so that i test with a live server and not my localhost